# AIR 3.6 iOS - Load external SWF with ABC

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

With AIR 3.6, is it finally possible to load an EXTERNAL swf file with AS3 code from the web and use it on the iOS device?

I see on [their web page](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/air/) they say the new features include:

> Packaging and Loading Multiple SWFs: This feature provides developers better memory management by allowing them to load the assets they need dynamically at ANY time from multiple SWFs and not have to load it up-front.

Just to make it clear, does this mean it only work for swfs packaged with the application, or also with externals swfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was just announced in AIR 3.7 not 3.6.

AIR 3.6 includes the ability to package multiple swf's with your iOS app but does not allow you to download them from an external server.

AIR 3.7 looks to give you the ability to load external swf's from a website.

> Application developers will be able to host their secondary SWFs on an External server and load them on demand as per their application
>   logic using this feature. The loading secondary SWFs which have any ABC code in AOT mode, which worked for just locally packaged
>   SWFs earlier, will now work for loading SWFs externally as well

It looks like the bytecode will be contained in your application binary

> During IPA packaging, ADT extracts the Actioscript code from all child SWFs which are specified within the sample text file, adds it to the
>   final executable and moves the stripped SWFs into the "externalStrippedSwfs" folder created in the current working directory.

Check the release notes PDF for an example,

http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air3-7_flashplayer11-7_releasenotes.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer f-a! You helped a lot! At the end i decided to go with more stable 3.6, since 3.7 is still in beta stage. So i want to use SWF that are packaged with the app. I used the method explained here http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/ , but i keep getting error "Reloading a SWF is not supported on this operating system.". The funny thing is, im not trying to RE-load the SWF, i just want to load and use it. How do i just load the SWF, and not REload it??

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a requirement that the external SWF file is compiled for Flash Player 11.6, with an internal version number >= 19.